# How to pull a list out of a multi-dimensional list in python?

Tags: python, list

I know how to pull an element out of a simple list using indexes, but I don't know how to pull a list that's inside another list.

Here's where I need this: I'm working on a snake game in pygame. I largely have the game running, but I'm having an issue getting the game to draw the snake's tail.

Here's how my code works: I've been using pygame.draw for the graphics. The 'snake' starts off as a box with an x and y coordinate. There's also another pair of x and y coordinates for the food (indicated with the variables posx and posy, to differentiate them from the x and y variables used for the snake's head). I have the game saving all previous coordinates for the snake to a list, which its doing fine (I checked by having the game print out what it was saving). My code for this part is this:

```
path.insert(0,(x,y))
```

'path' is the name of the list I'm using to track the snake's path.

I can move around and eat food with no problem (beyond the fact that my game is a bit unresponsive), the problem is if I try to implement code to draw the snake's tale.

The snake's length (how many 'food' its eaten) is saved in a variable simply called 'length'. I wrote this code to draw the snake's tale:

```
if length>0:
        for i in range(length-1):
            pygame.draw.rect(mainWindow, (255,255,255),(path[i], snakeSize,snakeSize))
```

Forgive the wrap-around on the last line.

I thought that what this would pull the individual x,y list from the 'path' list. But if I eat a piece of food, nothing happens beyond the food appearing in a new, random location. If I eat a second one, then the game freezes, and I get an error message that says:

```
TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
```

I guess it doesn't like how I'm trying to pull the x and y coordinates out of 'path'. I don't know how I could pull individual elements from a list from within another list.

Also, I don't understand why nothing happens the first time I eat food. All I know is if I change the formula from length-1 to length, then I just freeze immediately upon eating food. It doesn't seem to like length being equal to 1, and I have no clue why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing with `length-1` is that when you do `for i in range(length-1)` then when the game starts I'm guessing that `length` is equal to `1`, so `length-1` equals to `0` and the loop doesn't execute at all so no error is raised.

So, because we will fix that error soon, first of all change the loop to `for i in range(length)`.

---

As to your error, according to your information, `path` is something like:

```
[(1, 2), (4, 1), (6, 4)]
```

So now lets assume that `i=1`. By doing `path[i]` you get `(4, 1)`. So that means you are passing to [`rect`'s last argument](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect):

```
((4, 1), snakeSize, snakeSize)
```

But it expects a 4-tuple of ints. So you have 2 ways to go about this:

1. Simply pass it element-by-element that it expects. Something like:

   ```
   (path[i][0], path[i][1], snakeSize, snakeSize)
   ```

   And this is for sure a 4-tuple.
2. Another way, more "pythonic" one might say, is to use the [`*` operator to unpack](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/2845/unpacking-iterables) the tuple. It will look like this:

   ```
   (*path[i], snakeSize, snakeSize)
   ```

   To understand what this does lets look at a simple example:

   ```
   >>> a = (4, 6)
   >>> print( (a, 1, 2) )
   ((4, 6), 1, 2)
   >>> print( (*a, 1, 2) )
   (4, 6, 1, 2)
   ```

   And again, this is indeed a 4-tuple.

Comment: That answers my question, but after taking a break for a moment I  came up with an alternate way to do it: set the index from the main list to a variable then pull the index from that variable. Your method though still takes up one less line of code. Thank you.